# HTML in product attribute gets escaped

Tags: product-attribute, magento-2.2.5

So I've updated my Magento install from 2.2.2 to 2.2.5 and now it seems all my product attributes with 'allowed HTML' turned on get escaped.

So the value for the front-end is:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

What gets return when opening a product page:

```
 &lt;a href=&quot;https://www.google.com&quot;&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;
```

While the links were working before now they are broken. I've wiped all cache, resaved the product attribute, changed the product attributes, all to no avail.

Anybody got any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Click on show/hide editor on your attribute then paste the html and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Not an optimum solution. But can Try with using `html_entity_decode` function under extreme conditions.

Comment: Sorry but this is not a good solution. It’s better to become familiar with the platform instead of fixing something that isn’t broken.

Comment: @ShawnAbramson Sure, updated my answer, just in case :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Stores > Attributes > Product and select the attribute in the grid. Set `Is HTML Allowed on Front` to Yes. Flush the cache and reindex.

Comment: I've done all that already. "HTML Allowed on Front-end" was already checked since it was working on 2.2.2 before. Just not after the upgrade.

Comment: Its quite possible that Magent introduced a __('string escape') to it

Comment: I've done a clean install of Magento 2.2.5 through Softaculous which showcased the same issue. So I think it might be 2.2.5 indeed.

Comment: Did you ever get this issue resolved? I had to resolve this exact issue for a client yesterday. I can share the fix if you still need it.